# application start freezing and not responding after 1-2 hours of work

Tags: c#, winforms

I developed a WinForm application using C# and SQL server, the application work perfect without any issues when I tested it on my computer, and it's working fine, I also improved the Ram usage and the max ram usage is 200 MB I checked everything almost, but on the client POS machine, the application start freezing and not responding after 1-2 hours of work on-peak hours my clint has POSBANK machine 4G of ram, and I'm using a local network server and SQL server 2019 I don't know if this is from database connection or its a computer resource usage.

I have concerns about some code, I'm using 2 `flowLayoutPanel` one for the categories to get all the categories from the database and displaying it as buttons on `flowLayoutPanel1` and the other one getting all the materials under the selected category and showing them in another `flowLayoutPanel2`, the material tickets are a custom `usercontrol` contains a PictureBox and 2 labels (one for material name and the other for the price).

here is how I fill these `flowLayoutPanel` :
Materials `flowLayoutPanel`:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// GET MATERIAL SECTION START
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CategoryID"></param>
    private void Show_Food_UC(int CategoryID, int page_number)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { flowLayoutPanel2.Controls[i].Dispose(); GC.Collect(); }

            using (SqlDataReader reader = DBConn.ExecuteReader("get_materials_uc", CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@page_num", page_number),
                new SqlParameter("@page_rows", PAGESIZE),
                new SqlParameter("@categid", CategoryID),
            }
            ))

            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Food_uc UC = new Food_uc
                    {
                        Material_barcode = reader["barcode"].ToString(),
                        Material_Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["sell_price"].ToString()),
                        Material_name = reader["name"].ToString()
                    };

                    if (reader["image"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        byte[] image = (byte[])reader["image"];
                        image = Decompress(image);
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                            var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
                            UC.Material_image = bitmap;
                        }
                    }

                    UC.MaterialImage.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                    UC.Material_name_txt.Click += UC_PictureBox1_Click;
                    //UC.MaterialImage.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;
                    //UC.Material_name_txt.MouseDown += UC_PictureBox1_MouseDown;
                    //UC.MaterialImage.MouseMove += UC_PictureBox1_MouseMove;
                    //UC.Material_name_txt.MouseMove += UC_PictureBox1_MouseMove;
                    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(UC);
                    //bitmap.Dispose();
                }
            }
            ROWCOUNT = Convert.ToInt32(DBConn.ExecuteScaler("select count(categid) from materials where categid=@categid", CommandType.Text, new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@categid", CategoryID.ToString()) }));
            MAXPAGE = (int)Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(ROWCOUNT / PAGESIZE) - 1);

            if (MAXPAGE < 0)
            {
                MAXPAGE = 0;
            }
            Barcode_txt.Select();

            if (PAGE_number == MAXPAGE)
            {
                Next_but.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Next_but.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (PAGE_number == 0)
            {
                Back_but.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Back_but.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // Do some logging or something. 
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// decompress image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            dstream.CopyTo(output);
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

here is the materials User control code:

```
public partial class Food_uc : UserControl
{
    public Food_uc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Material_name_txt.Parent = MaterialImage;
        Material_name_txt.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        Material_name_txt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 0,0,0);
        Price_txt.Parent = MaterialImage;
        Price_txt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 108, 99, 255);

    }

    public string Material_name { get; set; }
    public decimal Material_Price { get; set; }
    public Image Material_image { get; set; }
    public string Material_barcode { get; set; }

    private void Food_uc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Price_txt.Text = Material_Price.ToString("C1");
        Material_name_txt.Text  = Material_name;
        Material_name_txt.Tag = Material_barcode;
        MaterialImage.Tag = Material_barcode;
        if (Material_image != null)
        {
            MaterialImage.Image = Material_image;
            //Material_image.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void Price_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Price_txt.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Price_txt.Text, Price_txt.Font).Width;
    }

    private void Food_uc_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Material_image != null)
        {
            Material_image.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the categories `flowLayoutPanel`:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// GET CATEGORIES SECTION START
    /// </summary>
    int cunt = 0;
    private void Get_Categories()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].Dispose(); GC.Collect(); }
            using (SqlDataReader reader = DBConn.ExecuteReader("search_categories", CommandType.StoredProcedure, new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@name", Categories_search_txt.Text.Trim()) }))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cunt = +cunt;

                    Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button button = new Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button
                    {
                        Animated = false,
                        BorderRadius = 5,
                        FillColor = Color.FromArgb(108, 99, 255),
                        Font = new Font("Droid Arabic Kufi", 12F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0),
                        ButtonMode = Guna.UI2.WinForms.Enums.ButtonMode.RadioButton
                    };
                    button.CheckedState.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(61, 54, 144);
                    button.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);
                    button.Height = 50;
                    button.Width = 140;
                    button.Tag = reader["ID"];
                    button.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
                    button.Click += FLB_Click;
                    button.MouseDown += FLB_MouseDown;
                    button.MouseMove += FLB_MouseMove;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // Do some logging or something. 
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    int DownAt;
    bool Moved = false;
    //private object mprcTabTip;

    private void FLB_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            DownAt = e.Y;
    }
    private void FLB_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int yy = Math.Abs(flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            yy += DownAt - e.Y;
            if (yy > flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 1 | yy < flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y - 1)
                Moved = true;
            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, yy);
        }
    }

    private void FLB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Moved)
        {
            PAGE_number = 0;
            CATEGORYID = (int)(sender as Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button).Tag;
            Show_Food_UC(CATEGORYID, PAGE_number);
        }
        else
        {
            Moved = false;
        }
    }
```

This is my SQL class helper :

```
class DBConn
{
    static string ConnectionString;
    private static void DBConnn()
    {
        if (Settings.Default.Trusted_Connection == false)
        {
            ConnectionString = string.Format("Server = {0}; Database={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};MultipleActiveResultSets=true", Settings.Default.server, Settings.Default.database, Settings.Default.user, Settings.Default.password);
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionString = string.Format("Server = {0}; Database={1}; Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true", Settings.Default.server, Settings.Default.database);
        }
    }

    public static bool Check_Connection()
    {
        DBConnn();
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connStr.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
    public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))//ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
    public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet_Paging(string sql, int _Start, int _MaxObj, string Table, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int));
            //cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds, _Start, _MaxObj, Table);
                //Int32 intRecCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value);
                //MessageBox.Show(intRecCount.ToString());
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }

    public static void InsertUpdate_Data(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ExecuteScaler(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                    var result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
    public static int ExecuteScaler_ReturnValue(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@inv_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var result = returnParameter.Value;
                    return Convert.ToInt32(result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static bool Exists(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        bool result = false;

        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return result;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    // Set the connection, command, and then execute the command with query and return the reader.  
    public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(String commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            // When using CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, the connection will be closed when the   
            // IDataReader is closed.  
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            return reader;
        }
    }

    public static void Delete(String commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ControlRemoved` is raised when you remove a Control from a Container, not when the Container itself is removed from another. You need to use the pre-defined `Dispose()` method of your UCs to dispose of the Images it contains. It's unclear what is the use of `Decompress()` method: what are you decompressing here? What kind of images did you store? Are you compressing, when storing the data (not shown here), images in what format? -- That backwards loop used to dispose child Control in the FLP can be appreciated, but remove `GC.Collect()` from that loop (it's no needed here anyway).

Comment: It appears you're not removing the event subscriptions. -- You're using a third party GUI Framework: how this framework behaves is unknown (to me, at least). It doesn't look like you're assigning unmanaged resource to these Controls, but I don't know how it handles its own resources internally. -- The db handling part looks ok.

Comment: Hello @Jimi, Decompress() is a method to decompress the image to display it in picturebox (compress the image and decompress it), and the image is normal images PNG JPEG. and I'm using Guna UI for GUI https://gunaframework.com/.
what is the best way to Dispose of the image in the UCs and how Can I remove the event subscriptions. thank you

Comment: Remove that Decompress thing. JPEG and PNG Images are already compressed (with a stronger algo). -- UserControls, when created, already provide a `Dispose()` method; it's usually inserted in the .Designer.cs file (and setup to handle components, child Controls are handled in a different way). You can move it to the code file to dispose of objects that reference unmanaged resources there (the Bitmaps, don't call `Dispose()` on the Controls, only on their content, the `Image` Property of a PictureBox, for example). You can remove event subscriptions in the same loop that disposes of the UCs.

Comment: The MemoryStreams you're using in the Decompress method can go. You're not disposing of those streams right now. A MemoryStream is kind of *special*, but if used to create/destroy Bitmaps frequently, may become an issue if not disposed of properly. -- Moving the UC's `Dispose()` method is just for convenience, it's easier to spot it and see that something is done with it, but it's not a requirement, of course.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for helping, I will try to fix all of them, but do you think this is the problem cause ??

Comment: I can only tell you what I see in the few lines of code you posted. I also don't know how this code is used (e.g., how often those Controls are created and disposed - or, how many times those Bitmap are not disposed or whether you have other unmanaged resources that are treated like that). -- If those third party Controls are not strictly necessary, you should try to replace them with corresponding standard Controls that have a well-know behavior (until you have debugged your app, at least). So you can also test the difference, when your app is *stable*.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your information, I want to show you how did fix these problems so you can correct me if that's ok with you. for the `picturebox` in the user control I dispose it of on ControlRemoved, for the unsubscribe to the event I'm using:`List<EventHandler> delegates = new List<EventHandler>();` Then in for loop I kill all the events after removing controls from  `flowLayoutPanel` but I dont know how to dispose `var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230391/discussion-between-rabeea-qabaha-and-jimi).

Comment: Read again my previous comment. From your description, you are not doing anything that I suggested. E.g., `ControlRemoved`, as already mentioned, doesn't work like that.